# PostgreSQL: Get rows which date is 5 days old than payment_date

Tags: postgresql, date

Currently I need to send an Email to all users that have 5 days with their payment due_date expired and are status=1 (pending to pay) for the current month and year because they might have future dates or past dates. example

due_date= 27/06/2018 send email after 5 days 1/05/2018

my Query to grab all users with a interval within 5 days is the following:

```
SELECT payments_payment.id, payments_payment.due_date 
FROM payments_payment 
WHERE payments_payment.due_date < NOW() - '5 day'::interval
AND payments_payment.status = 1
AND EXTRACT(year FROM payments_payment.due_date) = EXTRACT(year FROM NOW())
AND EXTRACT(month FROM payments_payment.due_date) = EXTRACT(month FROM NOW())
ORDER BY payments_payment.due_date ASC;
```

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Mureinik how to obtain the due_date that has 5 days expiration... from current date. I just need to do a loop for all the mails that has 5 days old expiration date.

Comment: I need to send an email to the user after 5 days of their payment is due. All Im getting is future dates with 5 days old. I need the dates that has already expired not future dates

Comment: @Mureinik I answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Need to make a different approach since the question is inverse for that reason I need to get the difference between 2 dates and see if it matches my day limit here is the Query.

### PostgreSQL Query:

```
SELECT due_date
FROM   payments_payment 
WHERE  payments_payment.due_date + interval '5 day' < current_date
AND payments_payment.status = 1
```

### Explanation

Get all payment dates where status equals 1 and month equals current month and year where the due_date substracted by current date is equals to 5 days.